# Make an extension method with IEnumerator

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting, extension-methods, quaternions

Hy everyone, i am tryng to make an extension method that essentialy let you do the rotate function of unity but you can chose the time in which is executed, and increment the value each time the routine is called. 
Example: `transform.Rotate(90,0,0, SecondsInWichMakeTheTransition);`

this is the code i write.

```
public static class RotateMeExtensions{

 public  static IEnumerator MoveObject(this Transform source, 
int x,int y, int z, float overTime)
{
    Quaternion target = new Quaternion();

    float a = source.rotation.x + x;
    float b = source.rotation.y + y;
    float c = source.rotation.z + z;

    target.eulerAngles = new Vector3(a, b, c);

    float startTime = Time.time;

    while(Time.time < startTime + overTime)
    {
        source.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(source.rotation, target, (Time.time - startTime)/overTime);

        yield return null;
    }
    source.rotation = target;

}
```

Right now i call it with an Button UI, but after the first time i use it ,it doesnt work anymore, the eulerangles stay at 90,7. I want to increment it each time by 90 degrees.
Thnak you Bye Bye

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it works as an extension directly but if you make it a simple function (without "this" before Quaternion) you could do the following

- On the function OnTriggerEnter just call StartCoroutine(RotateMeExtensions.MoveObject("fill with the variables"));

if you really want as an extenion create a dummy function like yours that the only thing that it does is call a global Monobehaviour Coroutine and you pass the other function. Something like

```
public  static void MoveObject(this Quaternion source, int x,int y, int z, float overTime)
{
    GlobalMonoBehaviour.instance.StartCoroutine(MoveObjectCoroutine(source, x, y, z, overTime));
}

public  static IEnumerator MoveObjectCoroutine(Quaternion source, int x,int y, int z, float overTime)
{
    Quaternion target = new Quaternion();
    Vector3 tempV = new Vector3(source.eulerAngles.x + x,
                            source.eulerAngles.y + y, source.eulerAngles.z + z);

    target.eulerAngles = tempV;

    float startTime = Time.time;
    while(Time.time < startTime + overTime)
    {
        source = Quaternion.Lerp(source, target, (Time.time - startTime)/overTime);

        yield return null;
    }
    source = target;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: in which namespace it is GblobalMonobehavior?

Comment: In my ideia it's just a monobehaviour that is attached to a regular object and has a public static variable that points to it's own instance like a singleton. The thing is, it has to be a monobehaviour instance because, if not, it will not run the coroutine

Comment: thnak you, now i know how to do extension with static and singletons. :)

Answer (score 1):

I will post the answer so maybe it will be usefull for someone else.
The problem was that i used

```
 transform.rotation.x
```

instead i should have used

```
transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x
```

Comment: so, the enumerator works with extensions natively? is it called like this - transform.MoveObject(10,10,10,10) ?

Comment: yes: `StartCoroutine (transform.MoveObject(0,0,90,1)); `. The only problem i encountered is when you increment the first parameter. you should increment outside the function, and then assign it to the extension method. `float a = source.rotation.x ;` .